# How to insert spanish á character in database

Tags: mysql

Hi I am delphi developer and I want to insert Spanish character 'á' in mysql database.
How do I insert spanish character in database?

Here is detail explanation,
When I fire below query some spanish character like é á does not get inserted in sql database.

Insert into tblTemp(Col1) values ('Los cambios será por artículos');

In database it insert text as 'Los cambios ser' only.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend to use utf-8 character set, see [MySQL manual, Unicode Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode.html).

Comment: Please narrow down your question. Where are you stuck at?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE xx (col1 varchar(200));
insert into xx values ('局层');
insert into xx values('Los cambios será por artículos')

select * from xx
```

Returns:

```
COL1
局层
Los cambios será por artículos
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/3c7de/1)